# Find, copy and paste all possible values of a cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row of cells (the row elements may vary) and another sheet with several columns of data. Let's say on sheet 1 we have 7 columns with data(first column with titles) and on sheet 2 we have some of those titles transposed on the first row. The task is to find all possible values for each title in sheet 2. Let's say in sheet 2 on the first cell we have title X, then I need to find all values corresponding to title X in sheet 1 and to take out the results from the 8th column of sheet 1. then do the same for cell 2 in sheet 2 and so on till the end of the row.

Can someone share a hint or any suggestions that might help me.

Actually I used the following code:

Sheets("sheet2").Select

```
    Dim Lcola As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Lcola = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, Lcola))
            With rng
                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A$1,MAP!$A$1:$I$" & lRowc & _
                ",8,FALSE)"
                Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
            End With
    End With
```

The thing is that I'm not sure how to repeat the function several times, or as much repetitions as I have on each variable from sheet 2 in sheet 1. And another issue that I'm facing is the vlookup function always gives me the first found item.

Comment: If you would edit the question to show what you've researched so far and the code you've attempted to write to 

perform this action, it will be a far better question and receive much better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a For loop, with your last Column from Sheet2 as your counter Max.

use iCol to keep track of which Column on Sheet2 you are copying and reading from.
use iRow to keep track of which ROW has the data you want on Sheet1.

Since you know you need the 8th column on the Sheet 1, it will always be Sheets("Sheet1"),Cells(iRow, 8)
and since you know the ROW that the column headers are located in Sheet2, Sheets("Sheet2"),Cells( 1, iCol) - if the header row is 1.

Then just grab a LastRow check on the Sheet2 Column in question and add to it one at a time.

```
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim lastRow1 As Integer
Dim lastRow2 As Integer
Dim matchRow As Integer
Dim tempVal As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim nRow As Integer

Private Sub IndexMatchLoop()

lastCol = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For iCol = 1 To lastCol

    'Assuming your row on Sheet2 is 1.
    tempVal = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, iCol)
    iRow = 1

    Call GetLastRow
    nRow = lastRow2 + 1

   'Looks up the value from Sheet2 Column Header on Column1 of Sheet1 one Row at a Time
    For iRow = 1 to lastRow1
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1) = tempVal Then
   'Copy the data from Sheet1 Column 8 in the Rows with the value to Sheet2, the nextRow of the Col
             Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nRow, iCol) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 8)
             nRow = nRow + 1
        End If
    Next iRow

Next iCol

End Sub

Private Sub GetLastRow()
    lastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(65532, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(65532, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1 List with Values in Column 8]
[image: Sheet2 with values under the Column header]

EDIT: typo in formula (was relying on autoComplete for "Int" instead of "Integer" 
EDIT: Adding Screenshots

Comment: Actually i have string variables only. I need once the variable from sheet 2 is found in sheet 1, then to copy the data of the same row for the 8th column and paste it under the same variable in sheet 2. And so on till all cases are found.In other words, let's say we have variable X in sheet 2 and we find it in sheet 1 5 times; then I need the data for those 5 cases copied from the 8th column of sheet 1 and pasted in sheet 2 under variable X.

Comment: I rewrote the solution given your requirements stated in your comment.  That should do the trick.  You will just do a few For Loops.  One to grab each column header value, and then a For loop inside that to check Sheet1.  A LastRow Check will get you the current last row on Sheet2 in the column you need to check.

Comment: thank you...this is exactly what i need. There is only one thing that I'm facing here. As it's my first time using loops, for some reason it's working only for the first column of sheet 2 even though the lastCol definition is working properly.

Comment: I changed the code above.  I had two variables being declared as Int, instead of Integer.  When I run this, it works as it should.

Try stepping through the code one line at a time and mouse over the variable names when you do.  That will tell you their current values and help you to know where it's failing, or what the problems might be.  Use F8 to step through one line at a time.  Otherwise, with the fix above, I just created tested this and it's working.

These loop practices can be employed in so many different ways.

Comment: hey, thank you for the feedback. Actually i changed this already but the thing is that the iRow loop keep circling. Using the F8 option i saw that only the second loop is getting executed and I'm not able to move to the next iCol. May be i'm missing something.

Comment: How many rows are you looping through?  Mouse over lastRow1.  You should have to loop though that many times.  Also, you could insert a break point on the Next iCol line, or anywhere for that matter to make stepping through faster.

Comment: What version of Office are you using?

Comment: hey, it's 2007. Actually I found what caused the issue. On sheet 2 the variables were named with Capital letters and in sheet 1 they all are lower cases. Now it works perfectly.